# How to add multiple page into document?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm working on `itext 7` and facing a problem that I can't find the way to add multiple page with pagesize (A4 landscape and portrait) difference into document.

**I've tried so far**

```
    public static byte[] GeneratePdf(string rootPath, string htmlString)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(stream))
            {
                using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                {
                    pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                    pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(htmlString, pdfDocument, GetConverterProperties(rootPath));
                    document.SetMargins(1,2,3,4);
                    document.Close();

                    return stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You set the default page size twice without anything in-between. Obviously, therefore, the value set in the first call simply is overwritten by the value set in the second call. What is your expectation?

Comment: My expectation is how can I add another page (ex: the first page is portrait and the second page is landscape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to add pages with individual orientation is the following:

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);
    pdfDoc.addNewPage(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    pdfDoc.close();
```

The PdfDocument.addNewPage() method accepts a PageSize parameter which can be used to easily orient the pages to your liking.

Regards,
Käsekuchen